# Displaying only one panel at once

Tags: gwt, panel, gwt-designer

I'd like to have the effect of one of two panels visible at given time in the same place on the screen. Perhaps I could use the DeckPanel but then in the designer I wouldn't be able to edit the hidden one. Maybe you could recommend a technique?

I've found a solution which works but is not pretty IMHO. Ie. in the code I insert the panel which I want to be visible and remove the panel which I don't want to be visible (from the containing panel).

Answer (score 0):

Just put both panel within another panel and then set their visibility.

```java
Panel mainPanel = new Panel();
Panel subPanel1 = new Panel();
Panel subPanel2 = new Panel();

mainPanel.add(subPanel1);
mainPanel.add(subPanel2);

subPanel1.setVisible(true);
subPanel2.setVisible(false);
```

And then when you want to see panel 2 you just do this:

```java
subPanel1.setVisible(false);
subPanel2.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this the "right" way, I'd suggest looking into the MVP pattern that GWT team in is [suggesting for maintaining large-ish GWT application](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/mvp-architecture).

Take a look at possible implementations: [mvp4g](http://code.google.com/p/mvp4g/) or [gwt-platform](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/). They will take care for you of switching views, as well as maintaining history (the back/forward buttons will work as they should) and many more.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for `Tablayoutpanel` Need not to maintain your own code .